# Custom iterator: how do I keep track of it?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I have this situation:

I have a class which keeps track of an array of pointers. I built a custom iterator which loops through this array.

My problem is on how to make it threadsafe, especially while incrementing/decrementing?

Here is a draft of the relevant parts of what I have:

```
typedef fruit * iterator;

class fruits
{
  private:
    fruit ** flist;
    int n;     //keeps track of position in flist
    int count; //number of fruits

  public:
    iterator begin() {n=0; return fruit[n];}
    iterator end() {n=count; return fruit[n];}

    iterator operator++ ()
    {
      return fruit[++n];
    }
}
```

The problem i see is that if two parts of the program create an iterator things won't work. How does C++ STL deal with it?

UPDATE: I have found the error of my ways. The iterator should keep track of where it is by itself. For that I created an iterator class embedded in my main class. Life is now good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard containers maintain their iteration state in iterator objects separately from the container, so there can be multiple iterations over the container at the same time. So `begin()` and `end()` return iterators, but don't change the state of the container; `operator++` acts on iterators, not the container. For a simple array like this, a pointer (to a `fruit*`, not a `fruit`) works perfectly well as an iterator, so you can just define `begin()` and `end()`:

```
iterator begin() {return flist;}
iterator end() {return flist + count;}
```

and use it like this:

```
for (iterator i = my_fruit.begin(); i != my_fruit.end(); ++i)
    do_something_with(*i); // *i is a fruit*
```

There's no problem with multiple threads doing this at the same time, as long as none of them try to modify the container.

On the other hand, unless this is a learning exercise to better understand how containers and iterators work, you're much better off using `std::vector` than implementing your own version of it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of saving state else in the iterator itself.